# Get the Hierarchical Structure of Taxonomy Terms (for all TermSets) using SP.Taxonomy.js

Tags: taxonomy, client-object-model

I am trying to get all the terms from the termsets within a term group, maintaining the hierarchy using `SP.Taxonomy.js` (SP2013).

Unfortunately, there seems to be no REST support for taxonomy in SP 2013. So, I am left only with CSOM (`SP.Taxonomy.js`). But unfortunately, CSOM only supports Async calls, so recursion is not working successfully to get the hierarchical structure, although we can get the flat structure of terms from a termset, using `termSet.getAllTerms`.

Has anyone come across this?